# How to select input value from onchange using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select and input tags. I am updating a value of a text input based from what is selected in the select tag.

Select Tag

```
<select class="form-control form-field-username form-field-users">
<option class="form-field-first-option" value="0" selected="selected">Select User...</option>
<option value="1">Peter Fel</option> 
<option value="2">Mark Getty</option>
</select>
```

Input Tag

```
<input name="user_id" id="user_id" class="form-control form-field-user-id" type="number">
```

Code for onchange select:

```
$('.form-field-username').change( function() {
    $(this).find(":selected").each(function () {
        var userId = $(this).val();

        $('.form-field-user-id').val(userId);

    });

});
```

I want to set the value of text input with user id of "user_id" to null or undefined if the onchange chooses the first value or user_id == 0.

Do you know how to modify the code? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value within the handler using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). The [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method is completely unnecessary here since there is only single selected option.

```js
$('.form-field-username').change(function() {
  $('.form-field-user-id').val(this.value == 0 ? '' : this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control form-field-username form-field-users">
<option class="form-field-first-option" value="0" selected="selected">Select User...</option>
<option value="1">Peter Fel</option> 
<option value="2">Mark Getty</option>
</select> 
<input name="user_id" id="user_id" class="form-control form-field-user-id" type="number">
```

Comment: I just have a question. How was your code able to find out the value of ":selected" without my $(this).find(":selected").each(function () {}); ??

Comment: yes, `$(this).val()` or `this.value` holds the selected value

Answer (score 1):

> Set empty on first option value.

```
<select class="form-control form-field-username form-field-users">
  <option class="form-field-first-option" value="" selected="selected">Select User...</option>
  <option value="1">Peter Fel</option> 
  <option value="2">Mark Getty</option>
</select>
```